# Prevent Notification thumbnail from showing when 3D-touching

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am creating notifications in an app with iOS >10. When I attach an image to this notification, it shows exactly as I want it, but when the user 3D-touch the notification, the image is shown almost full screen.
The image has almost nothing to do with my notification; it only works as an indicator, and I would like for it to keep the tiny 70px thumbnail-size when a user force-touches it, or remove it all together in this expanded state. Is this possible?
[image: Notification before]

This is exactly as I want it ^

[image: Notification after 3D-touch]

I do not want the image to grow so much!
Is there a way to prevent the thumbnail from being this huge? The image's size is 70x70..

Comment: Do u fiind any solution for this ?

Comment: @sivakrishna Yes! Wrote it as an answer, see below:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a `NotificationContentExtension` to solve this. This extension adds a new target to your project, with its own storyboard and .plist and everything. It was really overkill for my project, as it was a lot of work, but I wanted to get rid of that blown-up thumbnail.

This extension can communicate with your app, so we were able to put a lot of nice information into the extended notification, and it actually turned out looking great. You design everything yourself, like what happens when you 3D-touch a notification from the Calendar app. You could probably also use an empty xib/storyboard for this extension to simply remove the thumbnail, but I just went nuts and created gold. It is practically a `UIViewController` that you can design to show whatever you want.

I did read quite a few tutorials on the matter. [This](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-creating-custom-notification-interfaces--cms-27251) is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can i do it for both type of notificatios? I mean push and local

Comment: @sivakrishna Yes! When you create a `NotificationContentExtension`, you have to give it a "category name", which is somewhat like an ID for your notification-UI. When you post a notification from your server, simply specify the same category-id with a `category`-key. Read more at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html. Search that page for 'category' and you'll find it.